# What dose ‘the official system’ mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Mail means **the official system** used for sending and delivering letters, packages, etc.

In Oxford Advanced Learner’s Dictionaries, the definition of **Official** are

1.[only before noun] connected with the job of somebody who is in a position of authority

2.[usually before noun] agreed to, said, done, etc. by somebody who is in a position of authority

3.[only before noun] that is told to the public but may not be true

4.[only before noun] formal and attended by people in authority

Which one is suitable for this sentence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the sentence, *official* is used as an adjective describing the noun *system*.

The 4th definition you cite is the most appropriate - it is referring to the system that is deemed the correct, authoritative or sanctioned one.

In other words, there may be other methods or companies by which letters and packages might be sent and delivered, but they are *unofficial*. The *Mail* is the official, correct, sanctioned, or acceptable method to be used.